# With dbt. How do I use a jinja macro in a yaml file

Tags: macos, yaml, jinja2, dbt

I have a yaml file like this:

```
models:
       - name: test_view
        description: "test"
        config:
          meta:
            database_tags:
              ACCOUNT_OBJECTS.TAGS.ENV: DEV`
```

I am trying automatically change 'DEV' to PROD when it's in that environment. I have a macro that gets the variable from targets.name

This is the jinja code:

```
{% macro test_macro(target) %}
      {%- if  target.name == "dev" -%} DEV
      {%- elif target.name == "prod"  -%} PROD
      {%- else -%} invalid
      {%- endif -%}
    {% endmacro %}`
```

However, when I try to use the macro I get 'test_macro is undefined'

eg. ACCOUNT_OBJECTS.TAGS.ENV: {{ test_macro(target)}}

Is it that custom macros still cannot be used in yaml files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Macros are primarily for templating the SQL queries DBT compiles from its models. The YAML files are for  configuration; they are not themselves models and do not support custom macros.

I went looking, and [there is an active discussion](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/discussions/5097) about whether this could be supported in future, but as of the end of 2022 it is not possible.

Have you considered using a config block inside your model in order to set these metadata?

Comment: Thought this was the answer as it I wasn't sure if any progress was made since those discussions.